# Entity Framework Code-first migration mismatch between assemblies

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

I am building an Azure service (with a web role and a worker role), both of which reference a .dll file (*model dll*) with the Entity Framework Code-first model classes. The *model dll* has automatic migrations enabled.

I plan to make the worker role easier to extend, so I intend to upload some dll files (*worker dll*) to a blob, and code the worker to dynamically load and execute code from these assemblies. Naturally, the *worker dlls* would also reference the *model dll*, since they update the database.

My question is what would happen if I deploy a new version of the *model dll*, without also updating the *worker dlls*. The *workers* would reference an older version of the *model*, which did not contain the latest migration. Would EF try to downgrade the schema? Throw an exception? Work just as expected, as long as the entities are still compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you Rebuild the worker role assemblies and run it in staging deployment, and once testings are over you can switch it to production deployment without no downtime...

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh386336.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee517253.aspx
```

Comment: Of course I will do that, but I was wondering what **is supposed** to happen in my scenario. Testing the deployment this way (i.e. letting it run for a while) might let bugs stay hidden. Anyway, thanks for the links!

Comment: Just I want to know, why you want to dynamically load and execute the assemblies.

Comment: Because I want to be able to run one-time jobs (I have asked another question on the topic, you can see it on my profile): say that I add a new field in a table in the DB, and the worker would compute a value for this field each time an entry is inserted. However, I must also compute a value for each entry which is already in the table. This is a one-time job, and I need the worker to be able load its code from an assembly. Naturally, I can use the same approach for recurring tasks (e.g. retrieving data).